# Rails 5 project from API mode to non api mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A while ago I started a Rails 5 project in API mode, but I would like now for the app to also start rendering html and serving assets.

This is what my `application.rb` looks like now:

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module AppName
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
  end
end
```

Notice there's no mention anymore of `api_mode`.

However, when I try to run the server, I'm getting the following error:

```
/home/username/Sites/oneroster/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:8:in `<class:ApplicationController>': undefined method `helper_method' for ApplicationController:Class (NoMethodError)
    from /home/username/Sites/oneroster/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

What else should I do to make the app work again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `application_controller.rb` I had

`class ApplicationController < ActionController::API`

That had to be changed to:

`class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base`